How to edit the config.toml file of a container?
I'm new to docker. I downloaded a docker of ListMonk. At the beginning what I faced was the auto generated password from the installation.sh script. I tried to edit the config.toml file which didn't work at all. I edited both the postgres password and the admin password (Also edited the docker-compose yml file). But it never worked.
Later managed to stop the auto generation and used my desired password by editing the script.
My question is how do I edit the config file or the compose file of the docker and run after the edit?
Please help me out!
Pardon me if my terms or the word choices are wrong.

It sounds like you're on the right track but facing some confusion with Docker workflow. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to edit Docker container configuration and properly restart the container after making changes:
Steps to Edit Docker Config and Compose Files

Stop the Running Docker Container

First, ensure the running container is stopped. You can do this using:
docker-compose down

or
docker stop <container_name>


Edit the docker-compose.yml File

The docker-compose.yml file is responsible for defining the services, including their environment variables and volumes. Open this file and edit the desired values (like PostgreSQL and admin passwords).
For example:
environment:
  - ADMIN_PASSWORD=your_password
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=your_db_password


Edit the config.toml File
If the config.toml file is inside the container, you need to mount it as a volume to edit it locally. Add the volume in docker-compose.yml:

volumes:
  - ./config.toml:/path/in/container/config.toml

Edit the local config.toml as needed.
4. Rebuild and Restart the Container
Once you've made your changes, you need to restart the container to apply the new settings:
docker-compose up --build -d

This command will:
Rebuild the Docker image with the new settings (if necessary).
Start the container with the updated configuration.

Verify the Changes

To check if the changes were applied successfully:
Inspect the logs:
docker logs <container_name>

Access the admin interface with your new credentials.
If you’re still facing issues, let me know, and we can troubleshoot further!
